# How to disable message box of existing Folder in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, setuptools

I am using inno setup

I have tried the simple inno script code to install my program.exe, but the problem is that the setup always checks for the existing of the {app} (Distination Folder), and my goal is to hide the message box that says **"Folder is exist, would you like to install to that folder anyway?"**

my script is:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme
```

please see the picture bellow:

[image: https://i.imgsafe.org/a73ebd5e14.jpg]

Answer (score 3):

I found that:

```
DirExistsWarning=no
```

is working well, is there any other alternative ?

Comment: What alternative do you want? Isn't the `DirExistsWarning` exactly what you want?